# ionic4 display Object type data in template

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having a problem displaying data in the angular template with Ionic 4.

Here is part of the code:

## here I am sending data to the template page

```
item: any;
    
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, items: Items) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(item => {
      this.item = item;
    });
  }
```

## here I am reading the data

```
<div class="item-detail" padding>
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.about}}</p>
  </div>
```

## here is the data object value returned from the console

```
{
name: "Burt Bear", profilePic: "assets/img/speakers/bear.jpg", about: "Burt is a Bear."}
```

So the question is, how do I display these values on the HTML template with angular? This is giving me an error:

> FindingItemDetailPage.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init item prop, do not let it be any. e.g

```
public item = {}; // or a given class/model it's up to you.
```

Into the constructor there is no guarantee that item is there so ensure this case and apply appropariate behavior. (again it's up to you)

e.g

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute, items: Items) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(item => {
      this.item = item || {} // class/model would be better;
    });
  }
```

Lastly into the template you could set *ngIf

e.g

```
<div class="item-detail" padding *ngIf="item.name">
```

to ensure that there is an item, item.name is an example, you could use a property which guarantee that there is an item.

Comment: thank you very much @idmitrov your solution worked. i added *ngIf="item" in the template and now is ok. thank you.